# No module named 'PyQt5.sip'

Tags: python, pyqt5

when I tried upgrading my PyQt version to 5.14.0 and later landed up importing the packages as:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
```

it throws an error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Farhan Hyder .LAPTOP-R0TGSS2M/Desktop/BREATHE IN/Pred_WindowUI.py', wdir='C:/Users/Farhan Hyder .LAPTOP-R0TGSS2M/Desktop/BREATHE IN')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Farhan Hyder .LAPTOP-R0TGSS2M\Desktop\BREATHE IN\Pred_WindowUI.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

I also tried re-installing the libraries, but, unfortunately it didn't serve my purpose.

Comment: which version of PyQt5-sip are you using?

Comment: PyQt5 = 5.13.0 & PyQt5-sip = 12.7.1

Comment: Recommendation: update pip and then install pyqt5 `python -m pip --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1):

As per [eyllanesc's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796953/no-module-named-pyqt5-sip#comment107570137_60796953), try updating `pip`:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Then try reinstalling `pyqt5`:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pyqt5`

It worked for me (though I actually used `pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver pyqt5` for the new resolver).